# How do you declare a bind mount in NixOS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, nfs, nixos

I'm trying to declare a bind mount in my NixOS configuration. I'm trying the configuration snippet below, but it sends the OS into recovery mode when I test it out (using `nixos-rebuild test`). To be clear, I'd like `/data` to be reachable at `/srv/nfs` as well.

```
# 
# /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
#
fileSystems."/data" = {
  device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/bobloblaw";
  fsType = "btrfs";
};

fileSystems."/srv/nfs" = {
  device = "/data";
  fsType = "bindfs";
};
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 13):

Of course, right after posting this question I find this NixOS wiki article about NFS and bind mount examples:

https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NFS

TL;DR: Instead of `fsType`, I should have used `options`. At the time of writing this, the wiki is slightly out of date; `options` must be a list of strings.

This code snippet seems to work as expected:

```
# 
# /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
#
fileSystems."/data" = {
  device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/bobloblaw";
  fsType = "btrfs";
};

fileSystems."/srv/nfs" = {
  device = "/data";
  options = [ "bind" ];
};
```